# Error: AC_DEFINE() is not found to autoreconf --force --install

Tags: configure, autoconf

Description:
I am doing Customization for tacacs+ server open source code. While packaging 
i am tring to run configure to genrate Makefile.

Note: In open source tacacs+ tar is using autoconf 2.63 & on my build machine is having 
      2.67 autoconf version. Only this the env diff.

But get AC_DEFINE() undefined error as below:

```
d001:~/srcsvn/workspace_main_7.40_04102013_64bit/NMD2/64bit/os/usr.local/tacplus_merger/src/tacacs+-4.0.4.19.orig$ autoreconf --force --install
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `cfgaux'.
libtoolize: copying file `cfgaux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.in and
libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.in:45: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the file `configure.in` in line 45 and above and scan for `pkg-config` calls.

Then check if you have it installed (just type `pkg-config`). If this fails, you are missing pkg-config. Apply your distros way of installing software (rpm, apt-get, pacman, bee) and install the missing `pkg-config` package.

Comment: Nice, was the cause of the error I had also, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens all too often when something unrelated to it is misquoting the usage of the macro.

While it does not help much without knowing what the `configure.ac` looks like, you should observe the lines *around* line 45, rather than on that line, to figure out what's going wrong. Sometimes it can be just a misplaced `[]` quote.